# Avoid athena query round a float

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rounding, amazon-athena

I'm using s3 to store a float. When this float ends with 9, and I recover it via an athena query, I received the float rounded up.

I want the number not rounded. Is there any way to prevent the automatic rounding done by athena?

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean `1.9` is rounded to `2` or `1.999999999999999999999999` is rounded to `2`?

Comment: I have a test done for this. I've checked that when the float has only 5 decimals, (i.e. 0.56789), athena returns the same. But when athena has to return a float of 9 decimals, it rounds it (i.e. 0.123456789 becomes 0.12345679). I have solved this chopping to 3 decimals, but this seems like an athena bug or something...

Comment: No, that's how floats works when it does not fit to memory. Before writing it to S3 round to proper precision (e.g. 5 decimal places)

Comment: If this was true, then the comparison number should have to be rounded too. Instead, I have the following: $a = 0.123456789; $b = 0.12345679. This is only happenning when retrieving the number from athena. I think that's not a normal float behaviour...